# nodejs modal for login instead of login route

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, modal-dialog, middleware

Im building a nodejs (express) app using a user model for commenting thins etc.
For certain activities a user must have an account and has to be logged in. I'm using a middleware (function isLoggedIn) to check if a user is logged in. At first, I did this with a form that's shown if you go to the /login route. Instead of using a route, I want to use a bootstrap modal that shows up.

This is my login form that shows up when the modal is being invoked:

```
                <form action="/login" method="POST">   
                    <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                              <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="loginModalTitle">Login</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="form-group" id="formGroupLogin">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Passwort" required>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Login">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

It works perfektly fine when I put this on my navbar so that it's being invoked when you click the "Login" Button in the navbar.

But how can I invoke this modal when I want to guide to the login form within a middleware that checks if the user is authenticated?
In the past, I did this by routing to a route that shows the login form (using res.redirect("/login"). Now I don't want to route, I just need to expand the modal.

That's how my middleware looked so far:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect("/login");
}
```

How do I have to change it? Any Ideas?